# EFCore inheritance between multiple solutions

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, database-migration

I have the following problem:

I am using EF Core 6 and code first approach. I wish to have a TPT (Table per Type) inheritance for one of my classes **Item** which has subclasses **ItemA** and **ItemB** etc. (there will be more subclasses down the line). This is all supported nicely using toTable() in the ***onModelCreating*** method, but my issue comes because I want each of my sub-items to be implemented in different solutions, hence I can't define the DbSets of all my sub-items in my AppDbContext (which btw. inherits from DbContext) class. So **ItemA** has its own solution as does **ItemB** and so on so that they can be implemented separately and included as DLLs in the main project once they are implemented, but I don't know how to make sure that their tables are actually created by EFCore dynamically if they are included in the final publish. Is this even possible or am I perhaps going down a bad road.

Edit:
The reason I am trying to use multiple solutions is so that new Items can be developed by different teams completely separate to other Items. Once a new Item is done it should be “hooked” into the main solution. As Mark correctly says in the comments, these solutions will probably be very similar. Of course they will have a lot of their own classes as but from a data perspective at least they just inherit from **Item** which in turn used some other classes.

EDIT 2:
This is more or less the (simplified) structure of my *classes* in my project.
[image]
I have a **Product** that has a list of Item. Any subtype of Item should be able to be in this list. It is not important that it is a list, but it is important that Product can reference Items without knowing all the subtypes of Item being made!
Items on the other hand will all have reference to components (and other stuff) that will be the samme for each Item class. Then of course ItemA and ItemB can have references to their own stuff as well.

The reason I'm a bit concerned about a Microservice architecture is that I don't know how to keep track of the Product->Item relation. How can the "main" project store references to Items that are in completely separate databases? Duplicating DBs or maintaining consistency via events seems somewhat overkill as there may be MANY Item classes.

\Peter

Comment: you will have separate DB context in separate solutions. and run migration from from ServiceA and Service B instead of Service. While u have conflict , manually edit the migration file.

Comment: That really sounds like an error-prone solution to be honest. As I said there will be more subclasses later on.

Comment: When you say Solution, do you mean Project, or do you really actually mean Solution?

Comment: Yeah an actual solution.

Comment: Solution is just a "bucket" of projects - Visual Studio file, it has nothing to do with relations between projects.

Comment: You can have single DbContext defined in the main project, so main project will reference other projects with different services and so you will be able to configure every service in DbContext.

Comment: I thought of that, but I figured it would create some cyclic dependecies for my subclass repositories which would then be using my main project dbcontext. But maybe there is a way around that…

Comment: You can put your context in a .Net Standard library project. That way you can use one context and reference it in each solution.

Comment: @GHDevOps yes, but I don’t really see how I utilize that. I still don’t know how to add a dbset og my subtype to that context even though I can reference it. I really think what Fabio is saying sounds most correct, but I can’t figure out how to escape the circular dependencies.

Comment: We really need to know what you are trying to achieve having multiple solutions. Ideally, if these really are different solutions and cannot be grouped as one solution, you should have a different database for each. If this isn't an option, then I agree with @GHDevOps and think you should create a .NET library that the other solutions can import. By the sounds of it, these solutions will be similar in structure and would likely benefit from other shared resources in this library too. Please provide us with more information on these solutions if you want further help.

Comment: @Mark sure. I have tried to describe it in the new edit of the question. Hopefully it makes sense. The reason I did not like separate dbs are twofold: 1. I didn’t know how to reuse the other classes in the db (service is just one of many and is used by other classes), 2. At some Point I might need a reference to multiple services (a 1-m relation) regardless of subtype and I didn’t know if this is achievable if they are in separate dbs.

Comment: Your `DbContext` doesn't need to have any `DbSet<T>` properties. Each service can define a class like https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/EntityFrameworkCore/src/UserStore.cs#L96. You just need a way for each service to configure it's own part of the model at runtime / add-migration time.

Comment: You could use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/#grouping-configuration classes, then you just need a way to discover them all.

Comment: Thanks for that extra info @PNS. I run a very similar ecosystem at my place of work, and we still handle this by giving each solution its own database. We then import a core library into each sub-solution which can interact with the base solution using an API/Message Bus/etc. Each of your solutions should only have direct access to its own DB, and if you need to modify a different DB you should request that change in the relevant service and that service will modify the data. This will also help you when you need to make large changes to a solution (including the core solution).

Comment: @JeremyLakeman thanks, that is actually pretty much what I was searching for. Kind of surprised that it is so hard to find info about not needing dbsets even when I halfway knew what I was looking for.

Comment: @Mark yeah I actually do think that what you are describing is the “correct” approach, at least I think it is pretty clean. However, I have one worry. I will probably often need to reference multiple of my subservices from a different table. So say I have a ServiceManager class (bad name I know), that holds a list of services in my main project. How will I, in DB terms have a M2M table that can reference between ServiceManager and services from different databses (even though all these services have similar databases). Do you Follow what I mean.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not really following. References to other services are not normally done in the database. If you make a new service that needs to integrate with other services, you should make updates to all relevant services so they know how to interact with each other. As mentioned earlier, this is more often done with an API or message bus. A microservice architecture (which is what I think you are aiming for) should not have shared databases.

Comment: Take a look at this MS page on Microservice Architecture and see if that architecture is what you are trying to achieve. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/architecture-styles/microservices

Comment: I realize that my Service is an exceptionally bad word for this question so I have changed it to Item instead to avoid confusion. Item is just a POCO class. You may indeed be right @Mark that MicroServices are the solution I'm after but please check my last paragraph above with my concern. I realize that the Product class will have a List<Item>, but how can I represent this database wise when all the actual items are in separate db's?!

I really do appreciate all your help, really learning a lot! Hope you are enjoying the process (somewhat at least) as well :)